# Concat string in 2nd column if a condition is satisfied using sed bash

Tags: bash, unix

Csv file

```
A,12345,hello
B,67890,hi
A,123456,yo
```

Expected output: should add 2 zero at the end of the 2nd column if 1st column is A

```
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

Ive tried using this

sed “s/,/00,/2” file

But I havent have a condition

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better an `awk` use-case here:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    $1=="A"{$2=$2"00"}
    1 # aka print
' file
```

```
A,1234500,hello
B,67890,hi
A,12345600,yo
```

Don't you thing it's more readable and maintenable than `sed`?

If you have `sed` you should have `awk` too.

Comment: Yes, it’s more readable but the 1st column with B or any other value shouldn’t be deleted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two `sed` one-liners:

```
sed '/^A,/s/,/00,/2' file.csv
```

The `/^A,/` before the `s` command selects lines beginning with `A,`.
 Alternatively,

```
sed 's/^A,[^,]*/&00/' file.csv
```